# trouble of access, while using session_save_path()

Tags: php, session, count, limit

I met some trouble, in fact I've done a code in order to count the number of session that are logged in on the same time. Because I would like to limit the number of simultany connection.

So I've written the following code :

```
 <?php
  if ($d = opendir(session_save_path())) {
     $count = 0;
     $session_timeout = 3 * 600;
     while (false !== ( $file = readdir($d) )) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
          if (time() - fileatime(session_save_path() . '/' . $file) <            $session_timeout) {
             $count++;
               }
          }
        }
   }
if ($count > $societe['max_utilisateurs']) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `session` SET
    `temps` = now(),
    `login`='" . $_SESSION['login'] . "',
    `mouvement`='2'";
     mysql_query($sql) or die;
     session_unset();
     session_destroy();
     header('Location: ../');
     exit();
   };
    ?>
```

On the first line I do `opendir(session_save_path()` it returns to me the following mistakes

Warning: opendir(/var/lib/php5): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /mnt/getcash-trunk/GESTION/index.php on line 523

I do not understand where does it come from because I work on local server using ubuntu and full rights 777 on each folder and files.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: I'd suspect some session files are being used so they're locked for exclusive reading. Whey you say local server, do you mean that nobody else is using the site?

Comment: yeah because actualy it is not on production server because i'm just coding now and then I'll put on a real server

Comment: Did you check that /var/lib/php5 directory is readable by www-data user? Is 777 on it too? By default in ubuntu /var/lib/php5 readable by root user only.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I've tried using the root acces and it still does not work